# Printer Deploy with and custom preset profiles to Mac OS X workstations

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, applescript, printing

How would I go about deploying a network printer (Sharp MX-2600N) to Mac OS X machines that would include a custom printer preset profile (Embedded Printer User Authentication Code)?

Ideal Method of deployment that might be plausible is ssh command session. I am a newbie with unix commands.

Environment

Printer- Sharp MX-2600N

This printer is controlled by 'User Authentication' code that we have to configure on the printer presets.

Mac OS X Machines - Are joined to 2003/2008r2 mixed active directory environment.

Mac OS Versions - 10.7/10.8

Comment: I don't know a full answer to your question, but to start with, I would think of going into System Preferences > Sharing > Print Sharing.  Have you tried that?  (I know that you probably have to do more than that, but that may be a start.)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the drivers before you are able to setup the Mac systems to use that printer's Authentication method.  You'll need to download the drivers from [Sharp Website for MX-2600N Mac Drivers.](http://www.sharp-idncservice.com/DesktopModules/SharpDriver/SDdlViewFile.aspx?IDFile=14841&file=Mac%20OS%20Print%20Driver%20Package%20for%20Pastel-2.zip&location=%5C%5Csecnas%5Cmsgwebprod%5CContent%5CIndex%5Cidncservice%5CDriverFiles%5CMac%20OS%20Print%20Driver%20Package%20for%20Pastel-2.zip&From=SharpUSA)

Once you have downloaded that DMG, you'll need to open it, deploy, and install the PKG file inside correlating to the Mac OS version you are running on the destination system.  So for a client machine with Mountain Lion (10.8) you'll need to deploy that package to the machine either via SSH, email, Apple Remote Desktop, or some other method.  You mentioned through SSH so if you have a session open you would SCP it from your machine to that machine.

To install, you would run this command `sudo installer -pkg /path/to/package.pkg -target /`

Once the drivers are installed, you can then add the printer to the machine and have the user select the Secure Print feature in the Printing Preferences.